# How to add Existing snowflake user to ORGADMIN

Tags: replication

I have created two accounts in two different regions(Us-East & Asia). Now I am trying to do replication of database from US-East to Asia account.

Below are the steps I followed.

US-East

> select current_region();
> use role accountadmin;
> show global accounts;
> use role orgadmin;
> select system$global_account_set_parameter('SI49837', 'ENABLE_ACCOUNT_DATABASE_REPLICATION', 'true');
> show organization
> accounts;

alter database DEMO enable replication to accounts fe85487.ap_south_1;

After executing above alter statement I am getting below error.

> SQL compilation error: Object 'AP_SOUTH_1' does not exist or not authorized.

I am unable to add existing account(Asia Pacific) to ORGADMIN role.

Can anyone help me how to add existing asia pacific account to ORGADMIN account.